# Global ErrorHandler

Tags: php, function, include, global

I've made a php ErrorHandler which works only by using the

> include_once("ErrorHandler.php");

This needs to be added to every page, that I want to use the error handler, I'm wondering if there is a global function. So I can tell the server/php to call the "ErrorHandler.php" on every page, is this possible, within the limitations of php?

Comment: Is using namespaces and autoloading an option?

Comment: Is inversion of control an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [auto_prepend_file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) setting of PHP.